# UCS2/HexEncoded characters

Tags: php, ucs2

Any one can help me ? how could I get UCS2/HexEncoded characters

like 'Hello' will return "00480065006C006C006F"

This are the HexEncoded values:

0048 = H
0065 = e
006C = l
006C = l
006F = o*

Also in arabic (!مرحبا عالم) will return 06450631062d0628064b06270020063906270644064500200021

How I can get the encoded UCS2 in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UCS-2', 'auto')** works correctly to convert the string, but you'll have to do extra work to get the proper output in a browser.

You'll need to change the character set of your output to match UCS-2 in order to be able to use **echo** to output it to a page. Also, you may need to set the Content-Type via a **meta** tag in the header as well.

I've included three examples here in the following unicode variants: UCS-2, UTF-16, and UTF-8; as not all of them worked for me without tweaking in Internet Explorer. You may need to store your PHP files in UTF-8 to get proper results. Also, I am on an english version of Windows, so I can't enter your arabic string in proper RTL form. I'm sorry if your string is garbled here. I assure you that if you replace it in the location noted by my comments, you'll get the proper result. Finally, you may have trouble viewing UCS-2 and UTF-16 in internet explorer- there seems to be some oddities when the output is reloaded via a cache. However, FireFox 3.5.5 worked for all three encodings. If you're serious about making an app, I strongly recommend you consider using UTF-8 instead of UCS-2.

### UCS-2 Version

FireFox 3.5.5 (Ok, but FireFox says it is UTF-16BE on my test.)
Internet Explorer 7.0 (Not Ok. Didn't detect/convert Arabic properly.)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UCS-2');
mb_http_output('UCS-2');
echo mb_convert_encoding('<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UCS-2" /></head><body>', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('encoding: ', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding(mb_http_output(), 'UCS-2', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('<br />', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
// NOTE: Replace the string here with your phrase
$strTerm = '!مرحبا عالم';
echo mb_convert_encoding('$strTerm = '.$strTerm.'<br />', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('query string: '.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'<br />', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('original hex: '.bin2hex($strTerm).'<br />', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('transformed hex: '.bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($strTerm, 'UCS-2', 'auto')).'<br />', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('</body>', 'UCS-2', 'auto');
?>
```

### UTF-16 Version

FireFox 3.5.5 (100% Ok)
Internet Explorer 7.0 (Fail. May have to specify Byte-Order.)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-16');
mb_http_output('UTF-16');
echo mb_convert_encoding('<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" /></head><body>', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('encoding: ', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding(mb_http_output(), 'UTF-16', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('<br />', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
// NOTE: Replace the string here with your phrase
$strTerm = '!مرحبا عالم';
echo mb_convert_encoding('$strTerm = '.$strTerm.'<br />', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('query string: '.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'<br />', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('original hex: '.bin2hex($strTerm).'<br />', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('transformed hex: '.bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($strTerm, 'UTF-16', 'auto')).'<br />', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('</body>', 'UTF-16', 'auto');
?>
```

### UTF-8

FireFox 3.5.5 (100% Ok)
Internet Explorer 7.0 (100% Ok)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
echo mb_convert_encoding('<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('encoding: ', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding(mb_http_output(), 'UTF-8', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('<br />', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
// NOTE: Replace the string here with your phrase
$strTerm = '!مرحبا عالم';
echo mb_convert_encoding('$strTerm = '.$strTerm.'<br />', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('query string: '.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'<br />', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('original hex: '.bin2hex($strTerm).'<br />', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('transformed hex: '.bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($strTerm, 'UTF-8', 'auto')).'<br />', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
echo mb_convert_encoding('</body>', 'UTF-8', 'auto');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this web page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php), the Multi-Byte String module (mbstring) supports UCS-2. After enabling this module, you can use the function [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert a string from one encoding to the other.

Quoting the [documentation of the mb_convert_encoding function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
string mb_convert_encoding  ( string $str  , string $to_encoding  [, mixed $from_encoding  ] )
Converts the character encoding of string str to to_encoding from optionally from_encoding .
```

Comment: thx for your answer,

I put echo mb_convert_encoding("Hello",'UCS-2','UTF-8');

but it gives me the output Hello instead of 00480065006C006C006F

And didn't gives me the expected output

Any Advice or full example

Comment: In order to get the hex values of the underlying bytes of the string, you should call unpack, see an example in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php/885676#885676