# How to convert "UCS-2" to "UTF-8" by this way, with HTML, in PHP?

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding, ucs2

I have a HTML form, which is set in **ISO-8859-1**. Now, I want to convert `UCS-2` string into `UTF-8` string; this output `UTF-8` will print into `<input type="text" name="out" />`. And, my HTML form **must not** be changed the character set.

I have read these questions:

- [Convert UCS-2 file to UTF-8 with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942900/convert-ucs-2-file-to-utf-8-with-php)
- [UCS2/HexEncoded characters to UTF8 in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005358/ucs2-hexencoded-characters-to-utf8-in-php)

I try to solve my problem by this code:

```
<?php $str = $_POST['str']; ?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="str" value="<?php echo $str; ?>" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" />
</form>
<hr /><input type="text" name="out" value="<?php echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UCS-2', 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
```

When I input a word in **UCS-2**, such as: `Việt Nam`, it will returns: `�V�i�&�#�7�8�7�9�;�t� �N�a�m`. Why?

Is there any way to convert UCS-2 to UTF-8, by PHP; then, output into `<input type="text" name="out" />`?

Comment: 1) Your `mb_convert_encoding` call converts *from* UTF-8 *to* UCS-2. This does not sound like what you want. 2) I'm unclear why you need or expect you can transport UTF-8 over ISO-8859-1, why UCS-2 is necessary here, or how exactly you "type in UCS-2". Please clarify a lot.

Comment: How exactly are you *inputting* a word in UCS-2?

Comment: So you're simply *typing into the text field in your browser*? Why would you think that produces UCS-2?

Answer (score 0):

UCS-2 seems to have absolutely nothing to do with your problem. There's no UCS-2 involved at any step.

When you have a website or form which is using the ISO-8859-1 charset (or any other *subset* of Unicode), and you're entering a character which cannot be encoded in this charset, the browser will encode the character as HTML entity instead and send ISO-8859-1 encoded data containing HTML entities to your server. You can see that in your output if you squint a bit: `&#7879;`.

You can directly output this entity back into the browser to get the desired character. If you want to convert this HTML entity into an actual character encoded in, say, UTF-8, you need to HTML-decode it:

```
echo html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```