# php equivalent of java getBytes()

Tags: java, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String to byte array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php)

I am trying to find a php equivalent function of java getBytes()
Havent found anything yet but found some answers, nothing concrete.
http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10247795.html

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You mean the string function right?

```
$string = "texttexttext";
$bytes = array();
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
     $bytes[] = ord($string[$i]);
}
print_r($bytes);
```

--Output--

```
Array
(
[0] => 116
[1] => 101
[2] => 120
[3] => 116
[4] => 116
[5] => 101
[6] => 120
[7] => 116
[8] => 116
[9] => 101
[10] => 120
[11] => 116
)
```