# Unable to convert Java getBytes() to php

Tags: java, php

I am attempting to convert the following Java code to PHP but I'm having issues with finding the equivalent of getBytes()

**JAVA CODE**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] ar){
     String a="4F23DE12";   
     BigInteger b = new BigInteger(a.getBytes());
     System.out.println(b); //Result is 3766753334112104754
  }
}
```

The Java result is **3766753334112104754** but my attempt with PHP is not giving the same result.

**PHP CODE**

```
    use phpseclib3\Math\BigInteger;

    $a="4F23DE12";
    $b = new BigInteger($a);
    echo $b; //Result is 4
```

The PHP result is **4**. The issue seems to be from getBytes() and I have tried [String to byte array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php) and [php equivalent of java getBytes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226477/php-equivalent-of-java-getbytes) but still no solution.

In debugging it, I also tried `System.out.println("4F23DE12".getBytes());` in Java, the result was `[B@6d06d69c` but I haven't found an exact equivalent in PHP.

Please I will appreciate any help on how to use PHP to get the same Java result (**3766753334112104754**)

Comment: You use `BigInteger($p)` but set `$a`

Comment: In Java, this `BigInteger b = new BigInteger(a.getBytes());` should be `BigInteger b = new BigInteger(a, 16);` (which is `1327750674` in decimal).

Comment: @NigelRen was a mistake that I have corrected. Do you have any clue on the PHP equivalent?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The code I'm converting already uses getBytes(). So I need a solution with getBytes()

Comment: Your PHP code is incorrect. The string you pass is clearly hexadecimal, but you're asking PHP to interpret it as a decimal string. So it only sees the characters that are valid in decimal, which is only the first character, "4".  Use this instead: `$b = new BigInteger($a, 16);` and you get the same result 1327750674 as Elliot in his comment.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks. But how do I get **3766753334112104754** with PHP

Comment: Using `.getBytes()` is the wrong thing to do. For one thing, you won't be able to reverse the operation, as there are many byte arrays that you cannot print as a String. And secondly, `.getBytes()` uses the default character encoding, and that depends on the OS that you run on and your settings. At the very least, do `.getBytes("UTF-8")` to get the same result on all platforms. With that disclaimer, it's simple to get the same in PHP as in Java (3766753334112104754): `$b = new BigInteger($a, 256);` - the "base 256" encoding in PHP interprets the characters of your string as bytes.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for this, It worked. The .getBytes() code is lagacy code that am converting to PHP. So the PHP equivalent of `"4F23DE12".getBytes()` is `new BigInteger("4F23DE12", 256)`

Answer (score 0):

My question was solved by @ErwinBolwidt. Check the comments for more info.

With @ErwinBolwidt solution, the PHP equivalent of `"4F23DE12".getBytes()` is `new BigInteger("4F23DE12", 256)`.

Both will give you **3766753334112104754**