# Post request from Java App is cut on my Apache server

Tags: java, php, post

I have and PHP app where Java coder sends me a request just with picture. Here is my code:
I get `php://input` and write it to file as bytes

```
$query = file_get_contents("php://input");
$queryFile= fopen("/var/www/9292/querylog.txt","wb");
fwrite($queryFile, $query);
fclose($queryFile);
```

Then I remove all blanks from query. Can it cause the problem? And then I pack it in like `Hexadecimal` (because input that is in querylog file is hexadecimal)

```
$query = preg_replace('/[\s\r\n]+/', '', $query);
$queryHex=pack("H*", $query);

$inputImage=$queryHex;
$inputImage=trim($inputImage);
```

Also I trim it. I tried without treaming and the problem is the same.

The I write content of image to file by bytes.

```
$imageFile=fopen("/var/www/9292/inputPhoto.jpg", 'wb');
fwrite($imageFile, $inputImage);
fclose($imageFile);
```

So, the problem:
When Java coder makes a request, created picture has 17 k bytes, however it has 35 k. When I take a content of querylog file and put in into post request of Advanced Rest Client, it creates readable picture with 35 k bytes. I'm completely stacked. Java coder checks file right before putting it into output streams and he says it is fine. What can cause this problem? Can Apache somehow cut query? Can you advice me, what should I check?

[I came closer to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696492/issues-of-parsing-post-request-in-bytes-from-java-and-from-php):

Comment: May be you are missing encoding/decoding part?

Comment: Can you give me more info? Where and how should I encode it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238845/array-of-bytes-to-utf-8-string-in-php

Comment: Ok, and what exactly should I encode into utf in my case?

Comment: Unfortunately I can try it only tomorrow.

Comment: The problem is that I have to encode image. You sure that I should encode image into utf-8?

Comment: Without looking at Java code I can't tell it is due to encoded image or not, but that could be one possibility, that is why I made comment instead of answer.

Comment: Look my second question? Can you tell smth?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682218/post-request-from-java-app-is-cut-on-my-apache-server?noredirect=1#comment47538528_29682218