# PHP Passing an array to pack() function

Tags: php, arrays, pack

`pack()` syntax is (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

`string pack ( string $format [, mixed $args [, mixed $... ]] )`

so assuming I need to pack three bytes

`$packed = pack( "c*", 65, 66, 67 );`

But what if I have to pack an arbitrary number of bytes?

They could coveniently be stored into an array so I naively tried

```
$a = array( 65, 66, 67 );
$packed = pack( "c*", $a );
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there a way to make `pack()` work with an array ?

Comment: I think this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5473057/3933332

Comment: Not nice to unaccept a working answer for php when a php5.6+ specific answer was given later when php5.6 was not specified in the question :)... My voodoo doll of you is almost complete.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

At little late to the party, but for future reference, you can use the new `...` operator (v5.6+) to explode the array inline:

```
$packed = pack("c*", ...$a);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own function `array_pack` that internally calls `pack` using the [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) or the [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) functions so you can pass the correct number of parameters to it.

Something like this could probably work (not tested though... But you get the general idea)

```
function array_pack(array $arr) {
  return call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("c*"), $arr));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### use string concatenation instead of `pack()`

When packing **bytes** the packed binary data (string) may be produced by simply using `chr()`, concatenation `.` and a `foreach` loop:

```
$packed = "";
foreach ($a as $byte) {
    $packed .= chr($byte);
}
```

Where `$a` is the source array and `$packed` is the produced binary data stored in a string variable, as per the original question.

---

### benchmark

Having come, at the time of writing, with **5 different working solutions**, it's worth doing a benchmark in case the amount of data to pack is huge.

I've tested the five cases with a 1048576 elements array in order to produce 1 MB of binary data. I measured execution time and consumed memory.

### 2023 (update)

Testing environment: `PHP 8.2.7` - `macOS Ventura` - `CPU Apple M1 Pro`

(*only a single core is used of course*)

```
// pack with ... operator:     9 ms
// string concatentation:     10 ms
// call_user_func_array:      12 ms
// multiple pack:             46 ms
// array_reduce:           10918 ms
```

---

### 2018

Testing environment: `PHP 5.6.30` - `Mac OS X` - `2.2 GHz Intel Core I7`

(*only a single core is used of course*)

```
// pack with ... operator:    57 ms - 1.3 MB
// string concatentation:    197 ms - 1.3 MB
// call_user_func_array:     249 ms - 1.5 MB
// multiple pack:            298 ms - 1.3 MB
// array_reduce:           39114 ms - 1.3 MB
```

---

The `...` operator used directly with the `pack` function if by far the fastest solution (**[accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041396/1579327)**)

If `...` is not available (PHP version prior to 5.6) the solution proposed by **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841240/1579327)** (`string concatentation`) is the fastest.

Memory usage is almost the same for every case.

I post the test code if anyone interested.

---

```
<?php

// Return elapsed time from epoch time in milliseconds

function milliseconds() {
    $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
    return ((int)$mt[1]) * 1000 + ((int)round($mt[0] * 1000));
}



// Which test to run [1..5]

$test = $argv[ 1 ];



// Test 1024x1024 sized array

$arr = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < 1024 * 1024; $i++ )
{
    $arr[] = rand( 0, 255 );
}



// Initial memory usage and time

$ms0 = milliseconds();
$mem0 = memory_get_usage( true );



// Test 1: string concatentation

if( $test == '1' )
{
    $data = "";
    foreach ( $arr as $byte ) {
        $data .= chr( $byte );
    }
            
    $test = "string concatentation";
}



// Test 2: call_user_func_array

if( $test == '2' )
{
    $data = call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("c*"), $arr));

    $test = "call_user_func_array";
}



// Test 3: pack with ... operator

if( $test == '3' )
{
    $data = pack("c*", ...$arr);

    $test = "pack with ... operator";
}



// Test 4: array_reduce

if( $test == '4' )
{
    $data = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item) { return $carry .= pack('c', $item); });

    $test = "array_reduce";
}



// Test 5: Multiple pack

if( $test == '5' )
{
    $data = "";
    foreach ($arr as $item) $data .= pack("c", $item);

    $test = "multiple pack";
}



// Output result

$ms = milliseconds() - $ms0;
$mem = round( ( memory_get_usage( true ) - $mem0 ) / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 1 );
echo "$test: $ms ms; $mem MB\n";
```

Comment: another variant (instead of foreach) for completeness: `$packed = implode(array_map('chr', $a));`

Answer (score 1):

I use this function:

```
private function pack_array($format, $arg)
{
    $result="";
    foreach ($arg as $item) $result .= pack ($format, $item);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you can't use `...` operator:

```
$packed = array_reduce($a, function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry .= pack('c', $item);
});
```