# Converting C# code to php encoding issue

Tags: c#, php

I try to replicate this C# [code](http://rextester.com/YKHR97166) in php to get the same output(I cannot change c# code only php).And here I'm stuck

```
 public static string HashData(string textToBeEncripted)
         {
        //Convert the string to a byte array
        Byte[] byteDataToHash =              System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToBeEncripted);

        //Compute the MD5 hash algorithm
        Byte[] byteHashValue = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(byteDataToHash);

        return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteHashValue);
    }
```

The php code that I have made till now looks like this

```
$a = "test";
$a = mb_convert_encoding($a, "UTF-16LE");

$a = md5($a,true);

$a = unpack('C*', $a);
var_dump($a);
//with the output
array(16) { [1]=> int(200) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(158) [4]=> int(46) [5]=> int(199) [6]=> int(65) [7]=> int(159) [8]=> int(89) [9]=> int(14) [10]=> int(121) [11]=> int(215) [12]=> int(241) [13]=> int(183) [14]=> int(116) [15]=> int(191) [16]=> int(230) }
```

As you can see the output is the same as in the C# [code](http://imgur.com/cf1Eg63)
But I'm stuck at the function System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString().How to replicate this in php?Or there is a easier way to get the same output?(I cannot change the C# code sorry)

**Edit:** Based on Vasiliy Zverev answers since the php hash is different a little bit.I end up making aproximating the hash value of php with the C# hash

```
function validare_parola($parola,$dbHash){

$parola = mb_convert_encoding($parola, "UTF-16LE");
$parola = md5($parola, true);
$parola = mb_convert_encoding($parola, "UCS-2BE", "UCS-2LE");
$parola = bin2hex($parola);

$procent;
similar_text($dbHash,$parola,$procent);

if($procent>=90){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}

}

$parola = "testa";

$dbHash = "10095018710be2bcbbf9bba3f9d91ce8";
if(validare_parola($parola,$dbHash)){
echo 'PASSWORD CORRECT.You can log in.';
}else{
echo 'INCORRECT PASSWORD.Try again.';
}
```

As a side note don't use md5 for passwords use [php password hashing api](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)

**Edit2:** I ended up using Vasiliy Zverev solution.

**Edit3:** For the value "111111" there is different output in php...

**Edit4:** Vasily Zverev updated his solution and now is working as expected

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473011/how-can-i-convert-array-of-bytes-to-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, **updated**:

```
$a = "SF0D9G9SGGF0gdsfg976590";
$a = mb_convert_encoding($a, "UTF-16LE");
$a = md5($a, true);
$res = '';
for($i=0; $i<16; $i+=2) {
    // System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteHashValue) replaces invalid characters to 0xfffd ('я')
    // while PHP to 0x003d ('?') or empty string. So replace them like C# does
    $a2 = mb_convert_encoding($a[$i].$a[$i+1], "UTF-16LE","UTF-16LE"); // check if this is invalid UTF-16 character
    if(strlen($a2)==0 || $a[$i]!=$a2[0]) {
        // replace invalid UTF-16 character with C# like
        $v = 0xfffd;
    }
    else {
        // prepare a word (UTF-16 character)
        $v = ord($a[$i+1])<<8 | ord($a[$i]);
    }
    // print each word without leading zeros as C# code does
    $res .= sprintf("%x",$v);
}
echo($res);
```

Comment: What is input for that hash?

Comment: Try new version :) I search for invalid UTF-16 character one by one now.

Comment: Great job.Is finaly working.Thanks a lot for your help,like realy great job.

Answer (score 2):

Removed this variant because it was wrong. See correct code above.

Comment: Hi it works for "test".But if I type $a="parolaeste" I get different output on the php side.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong:
`return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteHashValue);`
Not all binary strings produce correct UTF-16 string. Some combinations of bits are invalid. While php bin2hex(md5()) doesn't do additional UTF conversion.
I will prepare a fix today later.

Comment: Please try out my new version in another answer.

Comment: If I type $a="111111" I get different output in php there is a 0 in plus.

Comment: LOL, this is because `hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint) System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()))` eats leading zeros.

Comment: This C# code is driving me crazy.Do you think is possible to do it in php?

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it out :)