# Convert image to byte with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have to send a picture to a webservice. The web service should receive the image as bytes (mayby bytearray) - not as a string... How do I convert the images to "byte" or bytearray?

I have tried this (without succes):

```
$image1 = file_get_contents("LINK TO IMAGE");
$image1BinaryData = "".base64_encode($image1)."";
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Reading it with file_get_contents should return an array of bytes, no? Or does it specifically return a string? If it does, use fopen, fread, and fclose

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried to directly read the image as binary data?

```
<?php
$filename = "image.png";
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: this is what file_get_contents() does.

Comment: I'm new, so please be patient :)
If I use this exampel, what variabel hold the bytes?

Comment: This solution works:
`$handle = fopen("LINK TO IMAGE", "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);`

Answer (score 3):

This is the actual byte array equivalent to what is generated in C# and Java.

```
$data = file_get_contents("test.jpg");

$array = array(); 
foreach(str_split($data) as $char){ 
    array_push($array, ord($char)); 
}
var_dump(implode(' ', $array));
```

Comment: for better performance use $array[] instead of array_push

Answer (score 0):

a php string is binary, so it's already in bytes.

get rid of base64_encode() and use urlencode() or rawurlencode()

Comment: Like this?
$image1 = file_get_contents("test.jpg");
$image1BinaryData = urlencode($image1);

Comment: probably. depends how you send it to the webservice. You may not need urlencode() at all.