# convert image to byte array using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have to call one webservice php side and send image byte array but my problem is this web service call when i am upload image so must need to send direct byte array in json post.

Comment: is this your webservice?

Comment: yes but i have not eligible for change or add code in webservice.

Comment: JSON doesn't support byte arrays. it's not easy to ship binary strings in JSON either, so your best best is send()ing a Blob or base64 string and decoding it in php.

Comment: Not sure if [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687270/convert-image-to-byte-with-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687270/convert-image-to-byte-with-php) is of any help!

Comment: as i have say i am not eligible to change or add coded because this webservice is already use for iphone and iphone developer send json with image byte array so i have to also use this webservice for my web.

Comment: @dandavis, JSON supports byte array, I've already implemented so

Comment: @Ishettyl i have already that code but i will not change server side.

Comment: @TirthakShah: not according to http://www.json.org/ it doesn't, and that what all the utilities are based upon. if you can't/won't change your server code, then you will have to give up on this feature.

Comment: @dandavis as Nikunj mentioned this service is already in use by Iphone Devices, so it is working with Json. And as I mentioned I also have used it.

It may not be better to use byte array like this, but It supports, you can even check SO for details.

Comment: @TirthakShah: do you have a link? i'm not 100% sure what you're referring to.

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya Is it **multipart/form-data** service ?

Comment: @jagad89 this webservice is only accept data with post and in json format with one profile image key and it value is byte array

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya Can you post webservice sample request? Generally it takes base64 encoded string.

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya you can convert image to base64 encoded string using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/) and base64 encoded string to bytearray using [this](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js)