# Sending file_get_contents() data over cURL

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I am trying to send an image to a web service API that asks for images to be sent as byte data.  After clarifying with them that the data from `file_get_contents()` is what they are looking for, I wrote my cURL script to send it to them, which is at the end of my post.

What I would like to know is if this is the correct way of sending `file_get_contents()` data to a web service?  Will the 'odd' characters that `file_get_contents()` produces be OK in transit or do I need to do something to protect them?

So far, none of my attempts have been successful - the API always returns the below error message.

I've only ever transferred images over APIs by base64 encoding them, so many thanks for any assistance you can offer.

**My coding to send to the API:**

```
// get the byte data
$image = file_get_contents("/path/to/my/image.jpg");

// url of api to post to
$url = "http://api.web.address";

// data to pass to api
$fields["username"] = "myusername";
$fields["password"] = "mypassword";
$fields["image"] = $image;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

**The error returned from the API:**

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ FExif  II*       ï¿½ï¿½  !           &#169; Corbis.  All Rights Reserved.    ï¿½ï¿½  Ducky       d  ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ &lt;?xpacket begin=&quot;ï»¿&quot; id=&quot;W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d&quot;?&gt; &lt;x:xmpmeta xmlns:x=&quot;adobe:ns:meta/&quot; x:xmptk=&quot;Adobe XMP Core 5.5-c021 79.154911, 2013/10/29-11:47:16        &quot;&gt; &lt;rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#&quot;&gt; &lt;rdf:Description rdf:about=&quot;&quot; xmlns:xmpRights=&quot;http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/&quot; xmlns:xmpMM=&quot;http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/&quot; xmlns:stRef=&quot;http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#&quot; xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:xmp=&quot;http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/&quot; xmpRights:Marked=&quot;True&quot; xmpRights:WebStatement=&quot;http://pro.corbis.com/search/searchresults.asp?txt=42-17167222&amp;amp;openImage=42-17167222&quot; xmpMM:DocumentID=&quot;xmp.did:50BE9125E81E11E38F86E55FB7D795DA&quot; xmpMM:InstanceID=&quot;xmp.iid:50BE9124E81E11E38F86E55FB7D795DA&quot; xmp:CreatorTool=&quot;Adobe Photoshop CC Windows&quot;&gt; &lt;xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID=&quot;8FBAF5153D10876B7ED66A56BC16FEE3&quot; stRef:documentID=... to System.Byte.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Byte.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out that it was a `byte array` that I should have been sending to the API.  I wasn't familiar with this in PHP, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php) helped me.  So my working code is now:

```
// get the byte data
$image = file_get_contents("/path/to/my/image.jpg");

// url of api to post to
$url = "http://api.web.address";

// data to pass to api
$fields["username"] = "myusername";
$fields["password"] = "mypassword";
$fields["image"] = unpack('C*', $image);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. Just have CURL do a standard file upload:

```
$fields = array(
    'username' => 'foo',
    'password' => 'bar',
    'image' => '@/path/to/your/image'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Note the `@` in the image field - that's a signal to CURL to do a file upload, using the path specified after the `@`. ALso note that http_build_query is NOT being used. CURL will recognize that you're passing in an array and do all the work for you.

If you're on PHP 5.5+, the `@` option is deprecated, and you have a new [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class for doing this.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer.  I've just tried implementing your code and now the API is returning:  `System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------a3eb5869b833.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()`

Comment: ok. then the api really does want a base64 upload. in which case your original thing should work, you just need `$fields['image'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents(...))` type thing.

Comment: thanks, but I have tried both `base64_encode(file_get_contents(...))` and `file_get_contents(...)` and the API doesn't accept either.  The API does say not to base64 encode images, so will that affect how the value of `file_get_contents` gets transferred to the API?  FYI, I've updated my original post with the full error returned from the API - just incase it helps work out what format it is expecting.