# PHP equivalent of getBytes in Java

Tags: java, php

I have the below Java code:

```
String Str1 = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");
System.out.println(Str1.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The output on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine is: "[B@7041825e".

What would be the above code's PHP equivalent?

Comment: Its not as straight forward, and takes a bit of data mangling, but you can reasonably fake it with pack() and unpack(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php

Comment: The `toString()` is redundant (Str1 is already a String), and the result is useless. What are you planning to do with the hashcode of a byte array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may use `strlen()` for that purpose.

In your case, `mb_strlen()` will do.

*... for more reading: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php*

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. PHP doesn't have a distinction between strings and a bunch of bytes.