# Alternative function for toByteArray() in php

Tags: java, php

In Java :

```
     int num=1455269554
     BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(num.toString());
     byte[] bytes = bigInt.toByteArray();
```

will return as:

```
    86
    -67
    -90
    -78
```

Is there any similar function in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to byte array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php)