# Converting Python ByteArray -> Php

Tags: php, python, arrays

I got a request from a friend of mine to convert a simple python script into php but I gotten stuck on a few small things and hopefully someone would be able to help me out alittle.
Is there a "easy" way to convert ByteArray in php?

In Python it is

> Value2 = ByteArray(Value1)

So in php it would be?

> $Value2 = ...($Value1)

Any help on this would be great.
Thank you. :)

Comment: Please share the function, PS: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray

Comment: This might be useful for you: [String to byte array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php)

Comment: Not familiar with python, but you do rememebr that a String in PHP can be addressed as `$str = 'Hello'; echo $str[1];` which would echo `e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what `Value1` is, so I'm assuming it's a string.

Use the [unpack](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function. This example converts a string into an array of bytes (int's actually):

```
 $byte_array = unpack('C*', 'A string here');
 print_r($byte_array);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 65
    [2] => 32
    [3] => 115
    [4] => 116
    [5] => 114
    [6] => 105
    [7] => 110
    [8] => 103
    [9] => 32
    [10] => 104
    [11] => 101
    [12] => 114
    [13] => 101
)
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. Yes, Value1 is just a string.