# how to covert xml file to byte array in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

This is sample xml file. I want to convert this xml file into byte array which is equivalent to C# byte array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DailyMidDayMeal>
<MDMHeader StateID="19" MDMServedDate="30/11/2017" BatchCount="1" 
BatchIDCreateDateTime="30/11/2017 11:02:47" BatchType="F">
<DailyTransactions>
<sno>001</sno>
<SchoolCode>19220111501</SchoolCode>
<MDMServedCount>34</MDMServedCount>
<ReasonCode>0</ReasonCode>
<TxnDateTime>30/11/2017 10:02:01</TxnDateTime>
</DailyTransactions>
</MDMHeader>
</DailyMidDayMeal>
```

Comment: @LucaKiebel... I want to covert it using php not C#.

Comment: Wow, sorry. I don't know how I could have missed that

Comment: @MaciejKowalski... used unpack('C*', $xml_file)... but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation of this question has been answered before.
See the approved answer here:
[String to byte array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php)

For completeness, I'll put this in the context of your question:

```
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('sample.xml'); // read file to string
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $xmlStr); // convert string to byte array
var_dump($byte_array); // output your resulting byte array
```

See the PHP documentation for details on unpack: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

Edit: I saw in a comment you mentioned this method didn't work. Attached are my results from a small test:

[image: Results]