# PHP pack() return warning and bad hex

Tags: php, pack

I have a key that I need to convert to HEX with pack ().

```
$key = "78787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878787878";
$keyBytes = pack('H*',$key);
```

But pack() return this:

```
p�������
```

I need this:

```
[0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x38]
```

what am I doing wrong? I follow exactly the manual that I have at my disposal.

Comment: The manual clearly states that pack() returns a **string**, not an array. I [cannot reproduce it](https://eval.in/923267) anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to byte array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php)