# PHP - Create a valid byte string

Tags: php

**INTRO**

I have two strings of bytes.
The first one is created starting from an array of hex codes and using a **for** cicle to create the byte string:

```
$codes = ["02", "66", "6c", "6a", "3a", "03"];
$bytestring1 = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($codes); $i++) $byteString1 .= "\x" . $codes[$i];
```

The second string is created writing it directly by hand:

```
$bytestring2 = "\x02\x66\x6c\x6a\x3a\x03";
```

**WHAT I EXPECT**

I expect that `$bytestring1` and `$bytestring2` are identical.

**WHAT HAPPENS**

When I send `$bytestring1` and `$bytestring2` to a client using **socket_send** command, the variable $bytestring1 appears to be a pure string and it doesn't work.

The variable `$bytestring2`, instead, is recognized as a string of bytes and it works.

**QUESTION**

How can I create a valid string of bytes **using the first method**?

Thanx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php

Comment: `"\x02"` is a *PHP string literal notation* which expresses the byte `02`. `"\x"` doesn't mean anything in particular, and concatenating it with `"02"` just results in the string `"\x02"`; strings' values aren't recursively interpreted at any time to resolve possible meanings that mean something in string literal notation. I.e. it would be pretty surprising behaviour if `$userinput1 . $userinput2` would be interpreted and result in the byte `02` because it happens to form the value "\x02".

Comment: I don't understand the reason of this unuseful and long reply, when vuryss user has replied in a very useful way. Sorry, but your reply doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

Like that:

```
$codes = ["02", "66", "6c", "6a", "3a", "03"];
$byteString1 = hex2bin(implode('', $codes));
```