# pdf to byte array conversion in php

Tags: php, arrays, pdf, byte

I need to convert Pdf file to byte array conversion in php.  I am looking for like this [result](https://pastebin.com/raw/L6KW1txi).

This result have byte conversation of Pdf file.

What id did:

```
$file = file_get_contents("pdf.pdf");
$fileData = base64_encode($file);
echo $fileData;
```

It does not works for me. how to convert PDf file to byte array?

Comment: Define “byte array” in the context of PHP.

Comment: @04FS I am not get your point , pls explain

Comment: It is unclear what exact result you want, so we can not tell you how to get there either. So, again, explain what you mean by “byte array” in the context of PHP.

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885597/string-to-byte-array-in-php

Comment: @04FS I update my question

Comment: "Does not work" is not a helpful problem description. The code you show will print the base64 encoded content of pdf.pdf (assuming the file exists and is readable), which seems to be what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the whole file into a string:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
```

If you want an array of one-character strings, you can do this:

```
$byteArray = str_split($fileContents);
```

If you want an array of integer ASCII values, you can do this:

```
$byteArray = unpack('C*', $fileContents);
```

Comment: I updated my question, what i am looking for result.