# I have a problem with spaces in folder name

Tags: php, linux, debian-stretch

I'm using the following function, to find files with specific file extensions within a given folder and all subfolders:

```
function FindVideoFiles($startfolder,$specificextensions){
        $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($startfolder);
        foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
            if (in_array(strtoupper(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)), $specificextensions)) {
                $files[]=array('nomedapasta'=>pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_DIRNAME));
            }
        }
        return $files;
}
```

`$specificextensions` is an array with `avi`,`mkv` and `mp4` as values.

`$startfolder` is a string with `/mnt/HD1_4TB/refazer/A View to a Kill` as value.

When I try to run the function, it throws me an error saying:
`failed to open dir: No such file or directory.`

The weirdest thing is, if I change the `$starfolder` variable to `/mnt/HD1_4TB/refazer`, the function works and return the files inside the folder "A View to a Kill" (even with spaces in folder name).
If i rename the folder "A View to a Kill" to "AViewtoaKill" and change the `$startfolder` variable to `/mnt/HD1_4TB/refazer/AViewtoaKill`, the function also work.....
so..... I think that my problem is the spaces in the folder name.
Can someone help me on how I can solve this problem without removing the spaces in the folder name?

Thanks

Comment: Great movie, great music

Comment: I would recommend looking at `A View to a Kill` and checking if it does indeed have the byte-sequences for spaces exactly that you think it does. For instance, maybe it has a hidden trailing space or other space-like character? Start in `/mnt/HD1_4TB/refazer` and just list the contents as [hex or bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466734/231316).

Comment: @ChrisHaas by following your tip, i got : 
/mnt/HD1_4TB/refazer/A View to a Kill
array (size=41)
.....
  22 => int 65
  23 => int 194
  24 => int 160
  25 => int 86
  26 => int 105
  27 => int 101
  28 => int 119
  29 => int 194
  30 => int 160
  31 => int 116
  32 => int 111
  33 => int 194
  34 => int 160
  35 => int 97
  36 => int 194
  37 => int 160
  38 => int 75
  39 => int 105
  40 => int 108
  41 => int 108
shouldn't the space character be "32" ? but in here it shows as "194" "160"... i'm starting to think that my problem is not php related, but debian related.

Comment: @ChrisHaas .... thanks for your thoughts. Do you have any idea on how i could solve my problem ?

Comment: Found it .... :     $startfolder=str_replace(chr(194) . chr(160), chr(32), $startfolder);

Comment: @ChrisHaas.... i would like to accept your answer as correct....but i can't :(

Comment: @FreddyKrueger, I'm not at a spot where I can post an answer easily. If you want to just post what you did as an answer and accept it, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score -1):

Use Explode and Implode function to do a successful search, example get the folder name from directory and remove all the spaces from it's name and compare, use folders name at backend without spaces. Try this.

```
$fileNameWithSpace = "A View to a Kill";
$fileWithoutSpace = (explode(" ",$fileNameWithSpace ));
echo implode("",$strWithoutSpace); //AViewtoaKill
```